# Displaying db data on UI using angularjs in a specific way

Tags: angularjs, json, database, scope

I have a problem related to the display of db table.

My data is right now in this format.

```
 Name          Age      Sex  

 Jack      |   20    |   Male 
 Jill      |   22    |   Male 
 Annie     |   19    |   Female 
 Stephanie |   17    |   Female
```

I am able to get the above data in $scope.data of Angularjs in this kind of JSON.

```
[{"Name":"Jack","Age":20,"Sex":"Male"},{"Name":"Jill","Age":22,"Sex":"Male"},{"Name":"Annie","Age":19,"Sex":"Female"},{"Name":"Stephanie","Age":17,"Sex":"Female"}]
```

I want to display this on the UI using Angularjs in this format

```
          Male
  Jack      |     20
  Jill      |     22

         Female
  Annie     |     19
  Stephanie |     17
```

Comment: First group by them with gender then loop on male and female

Comment: the json you have provided is incorrect. Provide a valid json using https://jsonlint.com

Comment: @ShashankVivek done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {  
  $scope.data = [
    { Name: 'Jack', Age: 20, Sex: 'Male' },   
    { Name: 'Jill', Age: 22, Sex: 'Male' }, 
    { Name: 'Annie', Age: 19, Sex: 'Female' }, 
    { Name: 'Stephanie', Age: 17, Sex: 'Female'}
  ];
  $scope.sexes = $scope.data.map(function(x) { return x.Sex; })
    .filter(function(value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index; });
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table{
  width:150px;
}
td{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <table ng-repeat='sex in sexes'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=2>{{sex}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='item in data | filter : {Sex : sex} : true'>
        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks like a great answer. Let me try it, just one thing, you have hard coded Male and Female in ng-repeat, I want the values to be there from the table

Comment: $scope.sexes = $scope.data.map(x => x.Sex)
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index); 
This is throwing syntax error on IE. Any idea on this?
.map() and => is throwing I guess

Comment: Hi Slava, can you look into this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444780/dynamic-addition-of-columns-from-db-using-angularjs