# Dynamic addition of columns from db using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, database

I have a problem related to the display of db table.

My data is right now in this format.

```
 Property     Value      Name  

 Age      |   20    |   Jack 
 Sex      |   Male  |   Jack 
 Diabetic |   Yes   |   Jack 
 Age      |   22    |   Jim 
 Sex      |   Male  |   Jim 
 Diabetic |   No    |   Jim 
 Age      |   25    |   Jessie 
 Sex      |   Female|   Jessie 
 Diabetic |   No    |   Jessie
```

I want to display this on the UI using Angularjs in this format

```
  Name      |    Jack   |   Jim   |  Jessie
  Age       |     20    |    22   |   25
  Sex       |    Male   |   Male  |  Female
 Diabetic   |     Yes   |    No   |   No
```

The names in the 1st table can be increased in the future in the db. So for a new name, new column will be added dynamically.

I am able to write logic till here.

```
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style="width:50%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-info">
                            <th >Name</th>
                            <th ng-repeat='header in names'>{{header}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat='p in properties'>
                            <td>{{p}}</td>
                            <td ng-repeat='item in totalData | filter : {property : p}: true'>{{item.value}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Now I am able to see values in the desired format. But the issue is I need to have one more filter condition i.e.  {item.name == header}. I am adding this condition because otherwise it can also display result like below

```
  Name      |    Jack   |   Jim   |  Jessie
  Age       |     22    |    25   |   20
  Sex       |    Male   |   Male  |  Female
 Diabetic   |     Yes   |    No   |   No
```

Here, ages are misplaced. So I want to filter that give value for Jack/Jim etc.
properties contain - Age, sex, diabetic.
names contain - Jack, Jim, Jessie
totalData contains every row data of the 1st table

Comment: What did you try? where are you facing issue? Show your code.

Comment: the best table would be with rows as: `user_id | name | age | sex | is_diabetic`. The re-arrangement should be done in backend

Comment: @VicJordan I have edited and issue is now mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I have come up with. Mostly I wanted to know how add multiple filters in ng-repeat. I have added that.

```
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" style="width:50%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="bg-info">
                                <th >Name</th>
                                <th ng-repeat='header in names'>{{header}}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat='p in properties'>
                                <td>{{p}}</td>
                                <td ng-repeat='item in totalData | filter : {property : p}: true | filter : {name : header} : true''>{{item.value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

If anyone has a better solution, I will be happy to implement it.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation and  jsfiddle about how did you achieve multiple filters in ng-repeat in above code??